# Refer to future output

Tags: output-formatting, output

in my notebook I would like to present output that follows from some code later on in the notebook. E.g. on page 10, in the appendix, I have a code producing a graphic, which I name *graphic1*. On page 5 I refer to this output. So on page 5 it just says *graphic1* and then subsequently the graphic follows.

However, when I quit the Kernel and then evaluate the Notebook, on page 5 the output is *graphic 1* and on page 10 the output is the actual graphic.

I have reviewed the delay function, but it has not helped me so far.

Is there a way to tweak this structure, so that upon evaluating the notebook it first processes the code on page 10 and then returns the graphic on page 5?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: make the cell on page10 that produces _graphic1_ and [`InitializationCell`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InitializationCell.html) by right-clicking on the cell bracket and selecting `Initialization Cell` on the menu.

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you also know how to permanently hide the input command on page 5 while still automatically presenting the graphic?

Comment: click on the cell bracket of the input cell to select the cell and uncheck the entry `Open` in `Cell >> Cell Properties` menu.